# I installed the facebook chat plugin and found the Uncaught error h - sdk.js 108

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I developed a website using magento ver.1.9.3 and used a basic theme named RWD.
Then I have to paste this code into Header (this code is derived from https://developers.facebook.com)

```
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="my-page_id" minimized="true"></div>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : 'my-App_id',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.12'
    });
};
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/th_TH/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Then there is an error. Uncaught h> sdk.js: 108 At frame PostmessageRelay

```
{throw u},0);return false}};return t.__wrapper}function r(t){try{return t&&t.callee&&t.callee.caller?t.callee.caller.name:""}catch(u){return""}}function s(t,u){return function(v,w){var x=u+":"+(n||"[global]")+":"+(v.name||"[anonymous]"+r(arguments));return t(j(v,"entry",x),w)}}if(l){setTimeout=s(setTimeout,"setTimeout");setInterval=s(setInterval,"setInterval");j.setWrapper(p,"entry")}return{guard:p,unguard:q}}f.exports={create:k}}),null);
```

Comment: It happens from time to time that a bug makes its way all the way into production ... Try the `en_US` version, and see if that throws a similar error. Whether it is specific to your language version, or appears to happen in all of them - file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs if the issue persists.

Comment: this error alert happens in only some pages. Other pages the code is working fine. Appreciate your advise on this. Thanks alot

Comment: The SDK handles all kinds of stuff, and postMessage is usually used to communicate between a 3rd-party iframe and the parent page - stuff like automatic resizing of iframes, etc. So depending on what specific social plugins you might be using on one page and not on another, it might simply go into different code branches/sections, so it is not that surprising that the error doesn’t show on every page, but only in specific constellations.